# Convert HTML to an image

Tags: html, image, thumbnails, cutycapt, iecapt

Duplicate

> [What is the best way to create a web page thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-web-page-thumbnail)

I want to display a thumbnail image of an HTML page.  How can I do this?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, like what programming languages you have

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-web-page-thumbnail

Comment: @Assaf - I think this question should have 'programmatically" and then it will not be a duplicate. Hope to get some answers. Interesting question!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to see if [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) or [IECapt](http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) are a good fit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Provide more information like if you are using PHP, ASP.net or a windows Application.
If you are using PHP for example you can profit of the variety of Open Source extensions that can do the work for you.

Comment: This is not really an answer :)

Comment: yeah, but this is not really a question. If he putted a clearer question, I would be able to give him a targeted anwser

Answer (score 0):

See how to [Generate a Thumbnail of Any Webpage using PHP](http://hasin.wordpress.com/2006/09/03/generate-thumbnail-of-any-webpage-using-php/).

Also have a look at [WebThumb](http://webthumb.bluga.net/home).

Answer (score 0):

I found several web sites that offer a service that will do this for you using http://www.google.com/search?&q=web+page+thumbnail.  For .NET Dll you could try http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/.

Answer (score 0):

How about

[PageGlimpse](http://www.pageglimpse.com/)

Used in sites such as

[DotNetShoutout](http://dotnetshoutout.com/)