# generate image (e.g. jpg) of a web page?

Tags: linux, thumbnails, html

I want to create an image what a web page looks like,
e.g. create a small thumbnail of the html + images.
it does not have to be perfect (e.g. flash /javascript rendering).

I will call use the code on linux, ideally would be some java library, but a command line tool would be cool as well.

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line program to create website screenshots (on Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/), a command-line utility. It uses Webkit for rendering and outputs in various formats (SVG, PNG, etc.).

Comment: looks good, but I would like a solution that is free for commercial use

Comment: actually, i think i might be mistaken, do I understand correctly that CutyCapt + QT are free to use for commercial use, uisng the LGPL license?
http://qt.nokia.com/products/licensing

Comment: According to CutyCapt's source code, it's license GNU v2 (see http://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt.cpp?revision=6&view=markup). You don't need a commercial version of QT to use CutyCapt, so you should be fine.

Comment: CutyCapt worked wonderful:

aptitude install xvfb
aptitude install qt4-dev-tools
wget http://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cutycapt/CutyCapt.tar.gz?view=tar
mv CutyCapt.tar.gz\?view\=tar CutyCapt.tar.gz
tar xfz CutyCapt.tar.gz 
cd CutyCapt
qmake
make

and that was it.

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can get it nearly perfect, and cross platform too, by using a browser plugin.

- [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648/) or [ScreenGrab](http://www.screengrab.org/) for Firefox.
- [6 Google Chrome Screenshot Webpage Capture Extensions](http://www.blogreign.com/6-google-chrome-screenshot-webpage-capture-extensions/)

[BrowserShots](http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/) is an open source project that may have some code you can use.

also see:

- [Command line program to create website screenshots (on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125951/command-line-program-to-create-website-screenshots-on-linux)
- [Convert web page to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968201/convert-web-page-to-image)
- [How to take screenshot of whole web page, rather than what shows on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090464/how-to-take-screenshot-of-whole-web-page-rather-than-what-shows-on-the-screen)
- [What is the best way to create a web page thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-web-page-thumbnail)
- [Convert HTML to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673023/convert-html-to-an-image)

Comment: It's hardly a programming solution.

Comment: have you looked at any of the links I provided? There are command line options, they all work on linux, exactly as the asker requires

Comment: cheers for the links, looks like some possible solutions in there.

Answer (score 1):

To take a screenshot in the terminal with ImageMagick, type the following line into a terminal and then click-and-drag the mouse over a section of the screen:

```
import MyScreenshot.png
```

To capture the entire screen and after some delay and resize it, use the following command:

```
import -window root -resize 400×300 -delay 200 screenshot.png
```

You may use a mixture of **xwininfo** and **import** to retrieve the window id of the browser and make a screenshot of that window. A bash script to automate this process would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
window_id=`xwininfo -tree -root | grep Mozilla | awk '{print $1}'`
import -window $window_id -resize 100x100 tumb.png
```

This script will create a 100x100 screenshot of Firefox on the current directory under the name tumb.png

Several sources show how to run a bash script from inside a Java application, google can help you on that. If you are in a hurry, check [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=681779) and [this](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14667).

Comment: to clarify, this will be called by a stand alone software (not a ui software)... so need to be automatic

Comment: I edited the answer above and added the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After reading this page, I was thinking, let me fire up midori browser: http://midori-browser.org/ and when I tried the -h option, I have seen:

```
  -s, --snapshot      Take a snapshot of the specified URI
```

QutyCapt is difficult to compile, and has many dependencies. Midori has it less. It outputs the PNG of the website into TMP folder. One can get the file with:

```
midori -s http://www.rcdwealth.com new.png 2>/dev/null | awk '{ print $4}'
```

After that, the file can be converted to thumbnail size by using ImageMagick's convert program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in Java, maybe you could look at browser automation using Selenium-RC http://seleniumhq.com

It's a little java server that you can install on the box and the program itself will execute remote commands in a web browser.

Steps like (this is pseudo code by the way, I code my Selenium in php and I can't recall 100% of the specifics off the top of my head)

```
selenium.location("http://foo.com")
selenium.open("/folder/sub/bar.html")
selenium.captureScreenshot("/tmp/" + this.getClass().getName() + "."
                               + testMethodName + ".png");
```

Actually, I just did a quick websearch for the exact syntax on that last one ... and this guy has a blog with what might actually be working code in java :) 
https://dev.youdevise.com/YDBlog/index.php?title=capture_screenshots_of_selenium_browser_&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

There's also a number of websites that provide this service "cross browser and OS" I just can't recall what they are.  Basically they've got a cloud of every single operating system and browser combination, and they log on with each machine, take a screen and store it on their site for you to come back to in a few hours when they're done.

Ahh... another websearch and it's yours :) http://browsershots.org/