# displaying tables with a telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm going to need to display a list of results as a response from a telegram bot I'm working on, and was wondering what's the best way of doing that...

I could "calculate" the amount of spaces I need to make it look semi-normal, but I'd rather have a better solution, if there is one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, the closest solution I could find is using "pre" inside the bot message (assuming it has parseMode=html), since the characters are all the same width.

I won't be using it eventually, but that's my 2 cents..

Answer (score 0):

i prefer generating HTML table as file and then convert it to an image with [some tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318490), and finally send the image to user by `sendPhoto` method.
by this method i can create a beautiful colored table with many options...

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be clickable (it's going to have links inside...)

Comment: please explain more
@trueicecold

Comment: @trueicecold so it is better to generate an HTML page and display external link of the page to users...

Comment: @علیرضا but then it wouldn't interactive with the bot :)

Comment: also you may generate the page with telegra.ph API so the user doesn't exit from telegram...

Answer (score 0):

I have used a [PHP library](https://github.com/viossat/arraytotexttable) to generate a tabular structure, then used `<pre>` tag to keep the spacing as it is as suggested by [trueicecold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471573/trueicecold)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it possible to post some code along with a screenshot of the table illustrating how the spacing is preserved?